# How do you call vertical carousal for website content?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know how you call the design in the picture below. The closest I came was *vertical carousal*, but all code examples I could find were about carousals for images. So my guess is that the people behind [Founders Pledge](https://founderspledge.com/) either use a different method to display content, or that such a design is a special case of an image carousal.

---

#### Some more details about this *vertical carousal*

The landing page of [Founders Pledge](https://founderspledge.com/) ...

- shows visitors where on the page they are currently at (see number 1 in the image)
- allows visitors to scroll down to the next div either by clicking on the down arrow (see number 2 in the image), by scrolling down, or by swiping on mobile.

  - what I like most hereby is that scrolling always moves one row(?) down or up. In other words, no matter how quickly or slowly I scroll down, I always land on the next row.

---

[image]

---

I would like to implement something similar on a website I am currently working on and hoped to find more relevant code examples with better/more fitting search terms than *vertical carousal*. I would naturally be happy over links to code examples/demos, but more fitting search terms should be enough to get me started.

Comment: I know that comments are not obligatory, but it would be nice to get an explanation of why the question and the two answers were down-voted (one of the answers has been removed as I am typing). I found that the now-deleted answer actually answered my question well (pointing me to *full page scroll* and [this example js library](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)). So even if my question might have deserved a down vote, I do not think that that answer deserved a down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The team at Founders Pledge uses pagePiling jQuery plugin by Alvaro Trigo

Find more details about the plugin [here](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling)

Answer (score -2):

Speaking of design, it has the [parallax effect](http://www.firewatchgame.com/) on the last "scroll".

"Nothing in life has a meaning except the one you give it."

It's called: On-Scroll vertically moving carousel items with navigation dots to the middle right and a sweet parallax effect on the last item (image) which made you question your reason of existence.

Thank you x)

Comment: I had looked into parallax before, but it seems different to me (i.e., typically no indication of where on the website a user is; faster scroll may skip a section). Another user had posted a (now removed) answer about full-page scroll (and [this example js library](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)), which appears closer to the example that I gave.